# Отображение спрайтов в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Меня интересует вопрос, почему в Unity в режиме Game спрайты так плохо выглядят, т.е. округлые формы очень теряют в графике и выглядят 'убого', хотя не в в этом режиме все нормально?

Comment: Стоит убрать комрессию спрайтов

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy можете подсказать как? Я делаю только первый проект и еще много чего не знаю

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy Я нашел, только не очень помогло, поставил на None ничего видемого не произошло

Comment: Выбираете изображение (не объект), в `Inspector`, в самом низу тыкаете `Default` и там выбираете `Max Size` побольше. 
**Edit:** Добавил ответ со скрином, для наглядности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбираете изображение (не объект). В `Inspector`, в самом, низу тыкаете `Default` и там ставите `Max Size` побольше. Также можно поставить `Compression` на `High Quality`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]